# Como posso permitir a inserção diretamente em uma DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Eu estou setando o `DataSource` de uma `DataGridView` com uma `List<T>`. Eu habilitei pelo designer "habilitar adição".

Mas não está aparecendo aquela linha com asterisco para adição de novos elementos.

Meu código está assim:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Valor> Valores
{
    get;
    set;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (Valores == null)
    {
        Valores = new List<Valor>();
    }

    dataGrid.DataSource = Valores;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando colocar uma `List<T>` no `DataSource`, entretanto uma lista não possui os recursos para ligar o componente da tela com a propriedade.

Ao invés de usar uma `List<T>` utilize um [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Este tipo fornece *two-way binding*, ou seja, o que você adicionar pela grid será adicionado ao objeto, e o que for adicionado ao objeto será adicionado a grid.

`BindingList<T>` implementa a interface `IBindingList` que contém a propriedade `AllowNew`. Esta propriedade será falsa quando não houver construtor padrão para `T`.

Conforme o exemplo:

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Quando o construtor esta vazio ou é omitido (sem haver nenhum outro) significa que você tem um construtor padrão. Neste caso sua grid irá mostrar o campo para inserir um novo elemento.

```cs
public BindingList<Pessoa> lista = new BindingList<Pessoa>
{
    new Pessoa { Idade = 20, Nome = "Teste 1" },
    new Pessoa { Idade = 22, Nome = "Teste 2" },
    new Pessoa { Idade = 23, Nome = "Teste 3" },
};
```

[image: pode adicionar]

Entretanto, se sua classe não possuir um construtor padrão:

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public Pessoa(int x) { }
}
```

[image: não pode adicionar]

---

Caso você precise utilizar uma `List<T>`, você pode criar um `BindingList<T>` a partir da lista, inicie uma propriedade do seu form com:

```cs
ListaBinding = new BindingList<Pessoa>( new List<Pessoa>() );
```

Utilizar esta lista para trabalhar com a grid e depois pode passar os dados que desejar para sua outra lista.